# Continuity of identity in $p$-adic $\mathbb Z$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, metric-spaces, divisibility

Say we have the $p$-adic metric in $\mathbb Z$ defined as $$ d_p(a,b)= \left\{\begin{align} &0 & a=b \\ &p^{-r} : p^r\mid (a-b), p^{r+1}\nmid (a-b) & a\neq b \end{align}\right. $$

I'd like to find all pairs of integers $p,q$ such that the identity $$ \mathrm{id}:\left(\mathbb Z, d_p\right) \to \left(\mathbb Z, d_q\right) $$
is continuous. I've done some work, and have gotten to the conclusion that the continuity of such functions can be stated as: $$ \forall r\in\mathbb Z^+ \ \exists s \text{ such that } q^{r+1} \mid {p^{s}} $$
So I'm almost there, but I'm stuck as to how to find more specific conditions on $p,q$. Any ideas please? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure to understand your statement $\forall r \in \mathbb Z, \exists s$ such that $q^{r+1} | p^s$ for negative $r$, so I'll assume it's only for non-negative integers (correct me if I'm wrong).

Just looking at this statement and taking $r=0$ I see that if there exists $s_0$ such that $q^1=q | p^{s_0}$ then for $r \in \mathbb N$, $q^r | p^{r.s_0}$ so your last condition could be more simply written $\exists s \in \mathbb N$ such that $q | p^s$.

This last condition is equivalent to saying that all primes in $q$ prime factorization are also in $p$ prime factorization. I'm not sure you can say something more precise about your last statement.

Comment: Yes, negative values of $r$ aren't considered in my statement, sorry.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a (maybe) more understable condition.

Comment: Oh that's great actually I was hoping for something in terms of prime factorization.